# Programatically get information about ROM memory type and size on Linux

Tags: c, linux, embedded, flash-memory

I need information form my C program about total size of flash memory and flash memory type on my embedded Linux. I can see these information when the kernel boots, but cannot find any other way to get them. Is this possible at all?

Comment: parse the info out of the dmesg log?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have /proc/meminfo? Would that give you the information you need?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your linux kernel is 2.6 newer and  you could check /proc/mtd*** for general information.

If that's not enough, check the source code of mtd-tools: mtdinfo.c

http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/external_mtd_utils/blobs/e783e75e09b4a0a519665afd7bdeaf2985e7a09c/ubi-utils/src/mtdinfo.c

check those print_XXXX_info functions.
You also need some external library to make that work.

kernel api for mtd interface changes once in a while, so make sure you have the correct version for your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

yes .it is possible using dmidecode utility of linux. here is the sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()  
{  
    char str[100]  = "dmidecode | grep -i 'ROM Size'";  
    system(str);  
    return 0;  
}
```

it will give you ROM size and if you do not grep for ROM Size then it also provide other BIOS information. if your embedded Linux doesn't have Dmidecode utility then you can get the source code from [here](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/). you can also analyse the part of dmidecode source code which is providing ROM info in case you not want to use system command and not want to dig other BIOS information.

Comment: Some other way? We don't have that command on our board, besides are security advisors strongly recommend against calling external programs.

Comment: That would only work if the board has a SMBIOS/DMI.  That is not a given on an embedded system, or indeed on any non-x86 system.

Comment: I Believe dmidecode directly accesses memory via /dev/mem.  You can do the same using dmidecode source as a guild.... assuming your board has DMI.  (my embedded x86 devices do not)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the kernel and/or bootloader source to see how it does it when it boots.  The method is likely to be specific to your hardware.